# Android: insert subject with autoLink="email"

Tags: android

I use a textview with  android:autoLink="email" to send an email being redirected to the smartphone Email or Gmail application. It works but I can't insert a subject. Are there people coming to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You could send an email this way :

```
String[] TO = {""};
      String[] CC = {""};
      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      }
      catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

And call this in the onClick event of the TextView.

You could also put some style to show it as a clickable link (underlined, colored).

*TO* will then contain the value of the TextView